# ssma Connection to Oracle failed. ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Tags: sql-server, oracle, database-migration

I try to migrate oracle database to sql server using Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant8.2 for Oracle, It is connected to sql server but it refused the login to oracle.
This is an image for the login form from ssma
[image]
and this is from the oracle sql developer and it connected successfully

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There may be a password case sensitivity. An application can force a password and name in large case. The `SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON` parameter gives control over case sensitive passwords.
Try to write a password in single quotes or change the `SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON` parameter to false 
`alter system set sec_case_sensitive_logon=FALSE;`

Check parameter `SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON`.

```
select value  from  v$parameter a where a.name='sec_case_sensitive_logon'

------------
TRUE
```

For example.

```
create user test identified by TestPass;
grant connect to test;

oracle@esmd:~> sqlplus test/testpass

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Thu Jun 13 06:33:25 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied


Enter user-name: test/TestPass

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

oracle@esmd:~> sqlplus test/'TestPass'

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Thu Jun 13 07:14:17 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

SQL>

alter system set sec_case_sensitive_logon=FALSE;


oracle@esmd:~> sqlplus test/testpass

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Thu Jun 13 06:35:11 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
oracle@esmd:~> sqlplus test/TestPass

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Thu Jun 13 06:35:35 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
oracle@esmd:~> sqlplus test/TESTPASS

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Thu Jun 13 06:35:47 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
oracle@esmd:~>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I reinstalled the last version of Oracle XE, Then It accepted the connection.